# Can't perform any operations over object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bluetooth, rxjs

I have two functions as given below. getRawData() and getBTRawData()

1. getBTRawData() just gets the data from Bluetooth from a phone
2. getRawData() gets the return value from getBTRawData() and tries to iterate over but that doesn't seem to work. I'm able to print the value inside a promise but I can't perform any functions on it.

```js
getRawData() {

        const result = this.getBTRawData().then((item) => {
            console.log("Item in this one: ", item);
            let flatten = [];
            for(let i in item) {
                console.log("something here");
                flatten.push(...item[i]);
            }

            console.log(flatten);

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }

    async getBTRawData() {
        let result = [];
        const res = await this.bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData().subscribe((data) => {
            //console.log("raw data");
            // console.log(data);
            var buffer = new Uint8Array(data);
            //this.raw_data_c.push(buffer);
            result.push(buffer);
            //console.log(this.raw_data_c);).map(
            // console.log(result);
        });

        return result;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what could be going wrong...I stubbed `getBTRawData` to resolve to an array of `Uint8Array`'s and getBTRawData worked fine

Comment: yea, getBTRawData does return an array of Uint8Arrays but I can't loop over the result, which I don't understand why

Comment: What happens?  Can you see that `item` is an array of `Uint8Array`s in the `then` callback?  (Does your `console.log("Item in this one: ", item);` print anything?)

Comment: (oh, and my bad...I meant to say `getRawData worked fine` in my first comment)

Comment: yea, it prints Array of Uint8Arrays but I can't seem to loop over. The loop won't execute at all.

Comment: I don't know why it would make a difference, but does it work if you iterate over `item` like this: `item.forEach(v => { flatten.push(...v); });`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: huh, then I don't know...sorry I couldn't be of more help

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`getBTRawData` seems to be returning an array, not a `Promise`. You should be able to directly work with the data from `getBTRawData` inside `getRawData` (assuming everything else works).

Comment: I've changed that but when I try to flatten it, it returns empty array and console for the result becomes object: 
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: Array(52)
0: Uint8Array [84]
1: Uint8Array(5) [82, 85, 69, 13, 10]

Comment: It seems like you just need to get rid of those `__zone_symbol__*` keys in the object and then you should be able to iterate over it

Comment: but ____zone_symbol__* is basically indicating its promise, right?

Comment: Not too sure about the details of your bluetooth library, so you might be right in which case I don't really know whats happening, sorry! If you print the data in `__zone_symbol__value` is it what you expect at least?

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help. Yes, the data is exactly what I expect.